# How to click on something else than an achor or button in codeCeption

Tags: laravel-5, phantomjs, codeception, acceptance-testing

I am trying to build a test scenario for acceptance testing. In my scenario, I want to click on an non-editable input field to trigger a JqueryUI calendar, and then click a date from the calendar.

The problem is that I can't seem to find any actions in CodeCeption that allows you to click on something else than a an anchor or a button.

The doc clearly states : Perform a click on a link or a button, given by a locator.

```
public function click($link, $context = null)
```

There are also similar functions that do something similar, but not with the left mouse button

```
public function clickWithRightButton($cssOrXPath)
public function doubleClick($cssOrXPath)
```

This seems so trivial that I can't find anything about it. Why isn't there a clickWithLeftButton? Am I missing something here? I'm just starting with acceptance tests with CodeCeption.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. `click` *is* `clickWithLeftButton`. It accepts CSS selectors and XPath expressions: http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#click

Comment: Yes, but it may only target an 'a', 'input type="button|submit" ' or a 'button' DOM object. I want to trigger open a custom JavaScript datepicker which is fired when the user clicks on the read-only field of type '<input type="text">'

Comment: Have you tried to find out the the CSS selector/XPath expression and clicking your custom datepicker? If you're not sure that it is loaded, then you should wait for an appropriate selector to appear.

Comment: This is answered in a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094032/codeception-cant-click-on-element-it-has-seen-just-before/68580465#68580465

Comment: Summary: Try using only a CSS selector for the thing you want to click on, that seems to work with `->click()` even if it's just a span.

Answer (score 0):

I may not fully understand the question, but have you tried

```
$I->waitForText('Text User would click on Here', 30);
$I->click('Text User would click on Here');
```